# Playing A Sound Clip Without MediaPlayer.Create from raw folder (Rather than stream or sdcard)

Tags: android, media-player

(Android)
I'm making an app with a few buttons, each of which has a short sound clip associated with them. They have their own OnClick statements. The code below plays a file from the SD Card as I'd expect...

```
public void Hello (View view) {
    ///ButtonClick Main Body.
    //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.hello);
    //mediaPlayer.start();

SoundPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        //TODO Auto-generated Method stub
        {
            SoundPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    String file = "/sdcard/Music/Hello.mp3";

    SoundPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        SoundPlayer.setDataSource(file);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        SoundPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

...However, how can I set the source to R.raw.hello (a Sound file) without causing an error? The current error message is "The method SetDataSource(String) in the type Media Player is not applicable for the arguements (int)". In case you haven't presumed, I'm using Eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: That's precisely what I don't want to do. That creates a new MediaPlayer every time, so eventually system resources are clogged. The app would quickly stop playing audio. Also I'm using one MediaPlayer declared outside the OnClick functions, so that it only has to be created once.

Comment: Then use a `SoundPool` object to load all the sounds you need using the load function. Save all the soundIDs returned by the `load` function and then just `play` that soundID you need.